# How do i remove all linebreaks?

Tags: xslt, newline, line-breaks

I have something like this:

```
<node TEXT="   txt A   "/>
<node TEXT="

       txt X

"/>
<node>
   <html>
      <p>
        txt Y
      </p>
   </html>
</node>
<node TEXT="txt B"/>
```

and i want to use XSLT to get this:

```
txt A
txt X
txt Y
txt B
```

I want to strip all useless whitespaces and linebreaks of @TEXT's and CDATA's. The only XML-input that is giving structure to the output are the `<node>`-tags.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The following transformation:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text"/>

<xsl:template match="*">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="@TEXT | node()"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="node/@TEXT | text()">
  <xsl:if test="normalize-space(.)">
    <xsl:value-of select=
     "concat(normalize-space(.), '&#xA;')"/>
  </xsl:if>

  <xsl:apply-templates />
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

when applied against this XML document

```
<t>
<node TEXT="   txt A   "/>
<node TEXT="       txt X"/>
<node>
    <html>
        <p>        txt Y      </p>
    </html>
</node>
<node TEXT="txt B"/>
</t>
```

produces the wanted result:

txt A
txt X
txt Y
txt B

**Do note the use of the standard XPath function [normalize-space()](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath#section-String-Functions)**, which strips off all leading and trailing spaces and replaces every sequence of other spaces with just one space.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want

```
 <xsl:strip-space elements="node"/>
```

explained [here](http://www.w3schools.com/XSL/el_preserve-space.asp). And this [article](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/xml/library/x-tipwhitesp.html) has a lot more details.

Comment: The <xsl:strip-space/> directive only works for *whitespace-only* *text* nodes and definitely not for attributes. Therefore this answer is not correct.