# writing XML on a single line with text and tag

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I have one XML file, which a XSLT transforms into a HTML file. I would like to write my XML in a javascript variable, **on a single line**, with all its **tag** and text inside the HTML file.

For example, I would like to transform this:

```
<root>
   <groupe>
      <link>
        ...
      </link>
   </groupe> 
</root>
```

into:

```
<script>
   var xml = '<root><groupe><link>...</link></groupe></root>';
</script>
```

I know that `<xsl:copy-of ... />` keeps text and tag, but I can't get rid of linebreaks and whitespace.  I have seen the `normalize-space` option but

```
<xsl:template match="@* | node()" >
   <xsl:copy-of select="normalize-space(.)" />
</xsl:template>
```

prints my output XML without tags.

Comment: Following will be helpful:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/324822/how-do-i-remove-all-linebreaks-using-xslt

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you could use something like

```
...
<script>
    var xml = '<xsl:copy-of select="." />'
</script> 
...
```

in your template.

What you need is to declare attribute indent="no" in xsl:output tag, e.g.

```
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="no"/>
```

And probably

```
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
```

could be also beneficial.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, `<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>` do the job. I completely missed this function. Thanks you very much @Jirka !